# Py4JJavaError: Cannot detect ES version when connecting PYSpark to Elasticsearch

Tags: python, apache-spark, elasticsearch, pyspark

I am encountering an error while trying to connect Spark to Elasticsearch and insert a DataFrame. The specific error message is as follows:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o130.save.
> : org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the
> network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a
> WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

appName = "mysql example"
master = "local"
spark = SparkSession.builder.master(master).appName(appName)\
        .config("spark.jars", "postgresql-42.2.6.jar,elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-8.8.1.jar").getOrCreate()

category_product_df = dataframe_from_table("category")

category_product_df.write.format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql") \
        .option("es.resource", "wael/test") \
        .option("es.port", "9200") \
        .option("es.nodes", "elastic:changeme@localhost") \
        .option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true") \
        .save()
```

When attempting to connect to Elasticsearch, I encountered the aforementioned error.

Here are some details about my environment:

- **PySpark version: 3.4.0**
- **Scala version: 2.12.17**
- **Elasticsearch version: 7.15.0**
- **Elasticsearch-Spark connector version:** **elasticsearch-spark-30_2.12-8.8.1.jar**

I have verified the accessibility of the Elasticsearch cluster and made sure that the necessary network connectivity is in place. Additionally, I have checked the Elasticsearch cluster configuration and confirmed that the host, port, and authentication credentials are correct.

I have also noticed that the error suggests setting the 'es.nodes.wan.only' property to 'true' when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance of Elasticsearch. As such, I have included this configuration option in the code snippet.

Despite these efforts, I am still encountering the error. I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully connect Spark to Elasticsearch.

Comment: Are you sure that the port and host have been defined correctly? I encountered the same error message with incorrect names.

Comment: yes absolutely i can access elasticsearch from navigator using localhost:9200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**i fixed it by running this instead :**

```
df \
    .write \
    .format("es") \ 
    .option("es.nodes.wan.only", "true") \
    .option("es.net.http.auth.user", "elastic") \
    .option("es.net.http.auth.pass", "...") \
    .option("es.nodes", "localhost") \
    .option("es.port", "9200") \
    .option('es.resource',"spark/test") \
    .save()
```

i guess the problem was  `format("org.elasticsearch.spark.sql")`not sure about it tho

Comment: Congrats on your first comment buddy. Glad it was the answer. Work on formatting it better